# Formgroup status is not set to Invalid if there is error in one field

Tags: angular

I have a form and when passportrank is set as error the formgroup status not changing as Invalid, if I navigate to next section the inline error message you are not eligible also get cleared.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm()
    this.createFormGroup.setControl('PERSONAL', this.formGroup)
  }

  initForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      passportRank: [],
      country: [],
    })
    this.formGroup.get('passportRank')?.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val === '3') {
        return
      } else if (val) {
        this.formGroup.get('passporRank')?.setErrors({ message: 'You are not eligible.' })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What is 'passportError' ? I don't see same control in your formGroup.

Comment: it's a typo. sorry I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the problem is that you need call to [UpdateValueAndValidity](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity) after the setError

BTW, generally it's better approach [create a custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators) instead of use setError.

```
errorValue(value:any){
  return(control:AbstractControl)=>{
      return control.value==value?{ message: 'You are not eligible.' }:
                                  null
  }
}
```

And you use

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  passportRank: ['',this.errorValue(3)],
  country: [],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your passportError with PassportRank

```
initForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      passportRank: [],
      country: [],
    });
    this.formGroup.get('passportRank')?.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val === '3') {
        return;
      } else if (val) {
        this.formGroup
          .get('passportRank')
          ?.setErrors({ message: 'You are not eligible.' });
      }
    });
  }
```